# Which java collection can I use?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I need to store a set of data structures that are defined by period of time (start, end) and counter for this period that holds some complex calculation results. The simplified definition of the data structure is as follows:

```
public class CounterBag {
    private Period period;   // collection key
    private Counter counter;
    // accessors
    // ...
}
```

the `Period` is as simple as:

```
public class Period {
    public DateTime start;
    public DateTime end;
    // accessors
    // ...
}
```

I need to have a collection that holds `CounterBag` objects defined by distinct `Periods`.
The collection needs to provide efficient lookup (here is the catch!) by `long timeInMillis` , so `HashMap` is not really an option, since I do not want to overwrite `equals` and `hashcode` of `CounterBag` (i need them both). The collection needs to be sorted by `Period` (by end date). `Period`s are of flexible duration which is not known to the part that would perform the lookup.

**I wonder is there an out-of-the-box collection in java standard API or in some open source library that can help me to solve it?** Some kind of sorted set or sorted map that enables implementing an efficient lookup by date. The lookup by date would return a `CounterBag` with `Period` the date falls within.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use TreeMap as its a Sorted collection (which makes the lookup efficient)

If your periods have regular intervals (which is the simplest form) you don't need such a collection.  You can just have a counter for each interval. e.g. a `int[]`

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the `Period`'s start and end are flexible and not known to the part that would perform a lookup, so the lookup will be done by date not by period.

Answer (score 0):

I would just extend @Peter Lawrey answer, use TreeMap with a custom comparator for your CounterBag.

This comparator will ensure that CounterBag which falls within the range is returned.

Efficiency of lookup will depend upon your comparator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If periods don't overlap then I'd suggest using `TreeMap<Period, CounterBag>`. When you need to get `CounterBag` given time in milliseconds you can use following:

```
// Initialize map
Map<Period, CounterBag> map = new TreeMap<Period, CounterBag>();
map.put(...);

// Prepare "query"
long timeInMillis = ...;
Period fakePeriod = new Period(new Date(timeInMillis), new Date(timeInMillis));

// Get bag for given time.
CounterBag bag = map.get(fakePeriod);
```

In this case either `Period` must implement `Comparable` or you pass your own comparator to the tree. Comparison of 2 periods should return 0 if they overlap (in our case if some real period includes our fake period with start and end time equal to `timeInMillis`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a `TreeMap<Long, CounterBag>`. You would access it using the `NavigableMap` interface:

```
NavigableMap<Long, CounterBag> map = new TreeMap<Long, CounterBag>();
map.put(bag.period.end.toMillis(), bag); // Get end DateTime as a Long


long lookupLong = 10000L; // or whatever

/*
 * Retrieves the greatest Bag whose Period's end is
 * less than or equal to the Long
 */
CounterBag newBag = map.floorEntry(lookupLong).getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because potentially any start time may qualify, given a sufficient duration, a simple ArrayList sorted by start time would be an efficient approach, especially if overlaps are allowed (yielding multiple results).  You'd iterate only up to the first record where start time > requested timeInMillis.